# Using an iframe on asp.net mvc 3 to create an editor

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, iframe

I am using an iframe on asp.net mvc 3 to create an editor. This is not working.

This is the javascript:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    document.getElementById('textEditor').contentWindow.document.designMode = "on";
    document.getElementById('textEditor').contentWindow.document.close();


    $("#save").click(function () {

    alert('ooosooooo');
    if ($(this).hasClass("selected")) {
        $(this).removeClass("selected");

    } else {
        $(this).addClass("selected");
    }

    on();

});

});


function on() {

var edit = document.getElementById("textEditor").contentWindow;
edit.focus();

//edit.document.execCommand('SaveAs', '1', 'e:\');
//edit.document.execCommand('foreColor', false, "#000000");
var ifi = document.getElementById('textEditor');
alert('ifi.innerHTML');
alert(ifi.innerHTML);

alert($("#textEditor").html());

//Trying to copy the content of text editor t hidden
//not working its always empty the textEditor
$("#hidden_field_id").val($("#textEditor").html());

edit.focus();
}
```

This is the html:

```
     @using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", target="textEditor"}))
       {

      @*this is the iframe*@
      <iframe id="textEditor" name="textEditor" width="100%" height="500px"></iframe>
      <input type="hidden" id="hidden_field_id" name="hidden_field_id" value="ww"/>
      <input type="submit" id="save" class="save" value="send" />             
       }
```

The problem is that when I insert text on the text editor when I press send/save the value copied from iframe to hidden is always empty "".

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
function on() {
    var edit = document.getElementById("textEditor").contentWindow;
    var html = $('body', edit.document).html();
    $("#hidden_field_id").val(html);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i did it like this :

```
function on() {


    edit.focus();

    var ifi = document.getElementById('textEditor');

    $("#hidden_field_id").val(ifi.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML);

    edit.focus();
}
```

thanks
pedro